# Java can't parse JSON generated by JSON.stringfy

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

After upgrading from rc-1 to rc-3 the `JSON.stringfy()` method is returning values with `\` at start and end of each value:

```
{
    \"perfil\":\"CLIENTE\", ...
}
```

How should I fix that?

code snippet:

```
post(url, data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return Observable.create(observer =>
        this.http.post(this.restConfig.baseUrl + url, JSON.stringify(data), {
            headers: this.getDefaultHeaders()
        }).subscribe(
            data => this.next(observer, data)
            , err => {
                console.log(err);
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this.redirectAuth();
                }
                observer.error(err);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

My Java RESTful services can't parse the output:

```
Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'perfil' that is to contain type id  (for class br.com.inbit.medipop.model.entities.impl.Cliente) at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@79f844cf; line: 1, column: 1]
```

class Cliente:

```
@Table
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CLIENTE")
public class Cliente extends Usuario {

}
```

class Usuario:

```
@Table
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "perfil", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "perfil")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Administrador.class, name = "ADMIN"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Colaborador.class, name = "COLABORADOR"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Parceiro.class, name = "PARCEIRO"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cliente.class, name = "CLIENTE"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dependente.class, name = "DEPENDENTE")
})
public abstract class Usuario {

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected PerfilUsuario perfil;

    ...
}
```

data before `stringfy`:

```
{"perfil":"CLIENTE","pessoa":{"tipo":"FISICA","sexo":"MASCULINO","nome":"Marcos Kichel","cpf":"911.111.064-36","rg":"1234"},"dependentes":[],"email":"anackichel@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: please post a snippet of your code

Comment: done @Apostolos :)

Comment: It's just escaping the quotes. Is it actually causing problems?

Comment: Yes, my Java RESTful services can't parse the JSON output.

Comment: cannot reproduce it actually

Comment: what does data look like before you try to stringify it?

Comment: added to the question @JarodMoser

Comment: interesting, that's what it should look like **after** it has been stringified. So it seems your code is stringifying something that's already been stringified. What happens if you completely omit JSON.stringify?

Comment: @JarodMoser You got it! It was being stringfied one layer above in between some complex code of the framework. Thanks a lot! Now would you post an answer suggesting what I just mentioned so I can accept it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are stringifying something that was already stringified. Take out the JSON.stringify() and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here actually not caused by escaped quotes, but the wrong data type of `perfil` field. In your java code it's expected to be an object, while in json you pass the String value `"CLIENTE"`.

So either make sure you send an object within "perfil" field or change the type of `perfil` field from `PerfilUsuario` to String

Comment: Actually, it is an `enum`, as you can notice on the `@Enumerated` annotation above the field. Enums are parsed as `String` by the `Jackson Body Writer`, it is not the problem, but thanks for your help anyway